# Integration in $\Bbb{R}$ involving Complex Transformation

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, dirac-delta

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}dx\int^{\infty}_{0}dy \; \delta(\sqrt{y^2-x^2}-a)$$
Here, $$ a>0 $$
and using the Jacobian $$x=x , \quad y=\sqrt{z+x^2}$$
Then,
$$\int^{\infty}_{0}dx\int^{\infty}_{0}dy \; \delta(\sqrt{y^2-x^2}-a)$$
$$=\int^{\infty}_{0}dx \int^{\infty}_{-x^2}\frac{dz}{2\sqrt{z+x^2}} 
\delta(\sqrt{z}-a)$$
$$=\int^{\infty}_{0}dx 
\left[\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{dz}{2\sqrt{z+x^2}} \delta(\sqrt{z}-a)
+\int^{x^2}_{0} \frac{dz}{2\sqrt{x^2-z}} \delta(i\sqrt{z}-a) \right]
$$
Why did this problem come to me??

$$\int^{x^2}_{0} \frac{dz}{2\sqrt{x^2-z}} \delta(i\sqrt{z}-a) 
= ?? $$

Comment: Why would you want to play with $\delta$ ? It doesn't make sense, until you study the theory of distribution.

Comment: i should solve that calculation, if you can solve that, please teach me...

Comment: So first you will need to know what is meant to have a delta function with complex argument.  (I don't know what it means, but maybe you do?)

Comment: I am sorry to disagree with previous comments, but the issue here has literally *nothing* to do with the delta function (or distribution). The issue has to do with the fact that we have a square root in the integrand. The question is as ill-posed as asking: 'What is the integral $\int_{-5}^{-3}\sqrt{x}dx$?' ... the integration bounds are inconsistent with the domain of the integrand. And this irrespective of whether we have or not a Dirac delta in the integrand (this is completely irrelevant).

Comment: @정재훈 We can't write a course on the theory of distribution just for you. By definition $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) \varphi(x)dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty 2n 1_{|x| < 1/n} \varphi(x)dx$ which converges and $=\varphi(0)$ whenever $\varphi$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Your *initial* problem is ill-defined. Since the radicand is $y^2-x^2$, this means that (for $x,y$ positive), $y$ should be larger than $x$. The integral you are after is in all likelihood 
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}dx\int^{\infty}_{x}dy \; \delta\left(\sqrt{y^2-x^2}-a\right)\ .
$$

Comment: why? there is no boundary about z. for integration range of x and y, z can be navative sign.

Comment: As far as I know, a square root is only real if its radicand is non-negative. Forget your $z$. I am talking about your *original* integral.